# Why do the points not get plotted on the raster?

Tags: r, spatial, raster, r-raster

I have a list of coordinates (latitudes and longitudes) and two rasters (one with 250x250 m squares and the other with 1000x1000 m square grids); both rasters have the same CRS (etrs89). When I plot the points (lat/lon) on the 250x250 sq m raster, it works but for the 1000x1000 m raster it doesn't. Please help!!

This is the code that I'm using for both--

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
points1 <- cbind(ds$lon, ds$lat)
points2 <- SpatialPoints(points1, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
points3 <- spTransform(points2,  projection(raster250)) 
#am just replacing this raster while trying to plot stuff on the 1000 m sq raster

plot(raster250)
points(points3, col="red")
```

The CRS for both the rasters is--
`+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs`

Comment: Would you mind to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Based on what you say it should work. If it does not you are wrong in some way, but there is no way to know for us how. Can you at least *show* `raster250`, `raster1000` and `points3` , as in `show(raster250)`.  Or indeed create an example using similar objects.

Comment: @www, the raster250 file I downloaded directly off of the internet as a raster. The raster1000 file I had to generate using the rasterFromXYZ() function and then assigned the CRS as mentioned in the question. Does this help? (I'm sorry it's sort of difficult for me to give out the data here).

Comment: @RobertH, the raster250 file I downloaded directly off of the internet as a raster. The raster1000 file I had to generate using the rasterFromXYZ() function and then assigned the CRS as mentioned in the question. Does this help? (I'm sorry it's sort of difficult for me to give out the data here).

Comment: This is not helpful as we have no ways to study your data and file. Good luck.

Comment: This suggests that you made a mistake. Please `show(raster1000)` !  You do not need to give out the actual data, all we need to know is the structure of the RasterLayer and that is easy to do.

Comment: This kinda helped me, thanks @RobertH- I had to change the units to km (instead of +units=m, I had to make it +units=km and it worked) on the 1000m raster! Any reason why this happened though?